# Call function outside window.addEvent() - mooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm using mooTools and I need to call function TestA() on click event on a tag but that doesn't work. I know that I can attach event do a tag via $().addEvent(...) but I need use approach like bellow.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.addEvent('domready', function () {           
          function TestA(){}
      });

    function TestB(){}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="TestA()">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you are defining your TestA function only when the DOM is ready? The reason TestA() is not working is because it is only defined within the scope of the function that is defined as the domready handler.

If you really do need to do it the way you're doing things then you'll need to scope the variable outside that function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var TestA;

    window.addEvent('domready', function () {           
        TestA = function(){}
    });

    function TestB(){}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="TestA()">Test</a>
```

Comment: Is this not exactly the same as the 2nd (and now accepted) answer? Only difference is that I defined the TestA variable properly in the global scope rather than just relying on the interpreter to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the *TestA = function (){}* notation instead of *function TestA(){}* :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.addEvent('domready', function () {           
          TestA = function (){}
      });

    function TestB(){}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="TestA()">Test</a>
```